# jQuery/Javascript - Fade in div onclick fade out another doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I want to pop up a menu on click of a div and I got it all working in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EhtrR/825/ but I cant manage to make it work on my code.

HTML:

```
<div id="clickOne" class="clickDesign">
<h2 class="fs20 nobold">Leafy Plants</h2>
</div>
<div  id="clickTwo" class="clickDesign">
<h2 class="fs20 nobold">Juicy Plants</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div id="leafyPlants">
Leafy Test
</div>
<div id="juicyPlants">
Juicy Test
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #leafyPlants{
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        top:50px;
    }

#juicyPlants{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
  $("#clickOne").on('click', function() {
   $("#leafyPlants").fadeIn();
   $("#juicyPlants").fadeOut();
});
$("#clickTwo").on('click', function() {
   $("#leafyPlants").fadeOut();
   $("#juicyPlants").fadeIn();
});
```

It doesn't show anything when I put it my code.

Comment: did you include jquery library..?

Comment: not really never heard of implenting it too im new to jQuery

Comment: You didn't tried so hard. Go to official JQuery website and see how to include JQuery. jquery.com

Comment: It works fine 

Check the demo : [CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/manublueheart/XKyp3/)

Comment: on my site it doesnt work

Comment: + i forgot to mention it is in WordPress

Comment: Have you got more than one JavaScript library loaded on your site? I know with WordPress that some plugins and themes can mix and load libraries that conflict with your functions. For example having jQuery and Modernizr at the same time. Which library does your function refer to?

Comment: in my fiddle i used jQuery 1.10.1 and im not using that plugin and how can i check which libary it refer's too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css

```
<style>
img {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#img1 {
    background: #b00;
}
#img2 {
    background: #c00;
}
#div1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #077;
    left: 10px;
}
#div2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #0b0;
    left: 10px;
}
br {
    clear: both;
}
</style>
```

This js codes

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#img1").on('click', function() {
   $("#div1").fadeIn();
   $("#div2").fadeOut();
});

$("#img2").on('click', function() {
   $("#div1").fadeOut();
   $("#div2").fadeIn();
});
});
</script>
```

And you HTML

```
<img id="img1"/> <img id="img2"/> <br/>
<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
```

It should work. Most probably you did not included jQuery library. I added it.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
```

Using it should solve your porblem probably.